# does dataset size affect accuracy of svm and knn

Tags: matlab, parameters, dataset, svm, knn

i have applied svm and knn on sound dataset to detect diseases . i applied both on two datasets individually and there is a good gap between accuracy of svm and knn , knn performing better. but when i combined both datasets and used knn and svm again their accuracies are almost equal . why is it so. can anyone please let me know the reasons of this . any refrence would help . thankyou

svm as a classifier,is performing good on a bigger dataset than small one. i want to know the reasons for it

Answer (score -1):

## Size really not matters!

Since the models (SVM & KNN) mentioned were machine learning, the size of the dataset is not a big deal.

### So what decides the performance?

The accuracy of the model could be leverage by provided the fair data, which is the collection of dataset with the classes in almost equal quantity.

If in case you could not find a dataset with more or less equal number of classes, try the preprocessing techniques such as - undersampling, oversampling and SMOTE.

Also, Please drop your feedback!

Comment: i am not using any augmentation technique on any of the datasets and both datasets are very imbalanced . but i cannot understand when i am doing multiclass classification for individual datasets svm shows 90 accuracy and knn shows 99 but when both datasets are combined svm and knn both show 99 accuracy. why svm is behaving this way.